# TakeWhile() function is not working properly with Boolean value.

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

According to the below code snippet when true value is not matched in fruit array the result value should hold all the values of array. However the TakeWhile() function is not adding the not matched value into my result list below is the code snippet.

```
 bool[] fruits = { false, false, false, false, 
                                  false, false};    
var query = fruits.TakeWhile(fruit => fruit.Equals(true));
```

Where as when it is string it works:

```
string[] fruits = { "apple", "banana", "mango", "orange", 
                              "passionfruit", "grape" };
IEnumerable<string> query = fruits.TakeWhile(fruit => String.Compare("orange", fruit, true) != 0);
```

Is there any way were we can make TakeWhile() function to behave equal to array of string when there is array of bool values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
var query = fruits.TakeWhile(fruit => !fruit.Equals(true));
```

It is even logical... Take the elements of `fruit` while they are...

- you wrote "equal to `true`"...
- I wrote "not equal to `true`"

```
String.Compare("orange", fruit, true) != 0
```

Means that if "orange" is **different** from `fruit` then `true`, else `false`

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the expression:

```
        bool[] fruits = { false, false, false, false, false, false };
        var query = fruits.TakeWhile(f => f);
```

This will correctly produce a query with 0 results, since none match.  It will only match those where the anonymous delegate instance returns true (i.e. f == true).

If you want to only count the "not matched" results, just change f => f to f => !f.